# Structured Data Testing Tool Reports "URL was not found", but the URL does exist.

Tags: google-search-console

When using the [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) to test my Mom's recipe site page titled [Perfect Chicken Fajitas](http://www.lindysez.com/recipe/perfect-chicken-fajitas/) I get the following...

### ERROR

> The URL was not found. Make sure the domain name is correct and the server is responding with a 200 status code.

However, if I curl for the same URL, I can see that a 200 results...

```
$ curl -I http://www.lindysez.com/recipe/perfect-chicken-fajitas/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: bb2_screener_=1457484500+172.4.33.122; path=/
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Link: <http://www.lindysez.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 09 Mar 2016 00:48:21 GMT
```

What could be the problem?